# android - widget help

Tags: android, widget

I've recently trying to practice making a battery widget that shows the current battery status.

I've typed the source code :

The java file :

```
package cam.widget.batterywiz;

import android.app.Service;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class batwiz extends AppWidgetProvider {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onUpdate (Context c, AppWidgetManager awm, int[] id) {
        c.startService(new Intent (c, UpdateService.class));
    }

    public static class UpdateService extends Service {
        public void onStart (Intent intent, int startId) {
            RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews (getPackageName(), R.layout.bat);
            rv.setTextViewText(R.id.battery, "80%");
            ComponentName thiswidget = new ComponentName (this, batwiz.class);
            AppWidgetManager m = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
            m.updateAppWidget(thiswidget, rv);
        }


        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

bat2.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/battery"
        android:src="@drawable/battery_icon"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
    >
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

android manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="cam.widget.batterywiz"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <receiver android:name=".batwiz">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                       android:resource="@layout/bat" />
        </receiver>

    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

</manifest>
```

can you guys try to figure out my mistake ??
because in my emulator it says "problem loading widget"
THX for the help..

Comment: What do you have in your logcat? There must be an excpetion or an error message.

Comment: actually it runs smoothly in my emulator, but when i try to drag and drop it to the homescreen, it says "problem loading widget"

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your manifest file, it says `@xml/bat`.

And your provider info should be in your `/res/xml` folder.

Also, you'll need to change your `RemoteViews` creation to 
`RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews (getPackageName(), R.layout.bat2);`,

and `ImageViews` don't have a `SetText` method.

EDIT:

changes

```
RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews (getPackageName(), R.layout.bat2);

android:resource="@xml/bat" />
```

(and move `bat.xml` from `layout/` to `xml/`)

```
rv.setTextViewText(R.id.battery, "80%");
```

This will not work, `ImageView` is not a child of `TextView` and so it doesn't have a `SetText` method.

Comment: ah sorry I forgot to add the bat.xml.... actually bat.xml's content is the appwidget-provider.. here's the bat.xml file :

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<appwidget-provider 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:minWidth="84dip"
 android:minHeight="176dip"
 android:updatePeriodMillis="300000"
 android:initialLayout="@layout/bat2"
 />